# Copy excel formulas with an interval of x rows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've got a big dataset in which I need to copy a lot of formulas with a 45 row interval. let's say that I want the following formula in row 100 till row 145: `averageifs(methane,date,"<="&A108,date,">="&A100)` and from row 145 and on, I want the following formula: `averageifs(methane,date,"<="&A153,date,">="A145)`.
How do I do it? 
[Example of how I want data at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PErTe.png) Attached is a file showing how I want my dataset to look like at the end (with a smaller interval).

Comment: What have you researched so far [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). SO is not a code writing service but a Q&A place for problems/errors with code.

Comment: which column you want to apply these formula?

Comment: @Karthick, I want to apply these to column U in my data sheet

Comment: what is methane,date? can you pls explain

Comment: @Karthick, thank you for your help so far! methane is measured mehtane in ppm, and date is the date and time in d-m-jjjj u:mm.

Comment: @JoepTummers did you check the below code?

Comment: @Karthick I did, I think it should work. The only problem is that i get the Run-time error 424: object required. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

pls have a look

```
Sub test()
    For i = 99 To 1000 Step 45
        Range("U" & i + 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(methane, Date, "<=" & Range("A" & i + 9), Date, ">=" & Range("A" & i + 1))
    Next i
End Sub
```